# Advance search through ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to do advance search through php and AJAX but i stuck and i don't know where is my mistake. plz guide thanks.........

My PHP code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    th {text-align: left;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$conn) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    $in = $_GET['str'];
    if (!ctype_alnum($in)) {
      echo "Data Error";
      exit;
    }
    mysql_select_db('firstdb');
    $sql = "select name, id , age, sex from name where name like '%$in%'";
    $display = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($display)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['sex'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript code and AJAX function

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
    function user(str){
      if(str.length==0){
        document.getElementById("userhint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } 
      else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("userhint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="user(this.value);" name="username" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <div id="userhint"><b>User info will be listed here...</b></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error occurred

[image]

I am new here plz help

Comment: Alright, you're problem is, that in the AJAX call, you are sending "q=" + str, but in the PHP you use $_GET["str"]. Use $_GET["q"] instead!

Comment: see below answer and use isset() function too with proper parameter passing from ajax i.e. q

Comment: @Gerrit Luimstra yes that was my mistake now got it thanks

Comment: @Masroor_Shah No problem!

Comment: @Gerrit Luimstra Can I select multiple columns in where clause like where name,sex,age="$in%";  ???

Comment: This is another question, and does not belong to this post. So officially this is not allowed on stackoverflow. But, yes you can. Use the AND command to seperate the "conditions" (if you want them both to contain something, else use the OR). Like `SELECT * FROM something WHERE age=12 AND name=test`. Or use the OR,  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Gerrit Luimstra okay bro thank you done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your http get request you are sending a parameter called `q`, but in the server side you are trying to fetch that parameter by the name `str`. so str is not found.

change the parameter name like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?str="+str, true);
```

Comment: Can I select multiple columns in where clause like where name,sex,age="$in%";  ???

Answer (score 0):

use isset to get no error

but you passing q=

```
 if(isset($_GET['str'])){ // it will  if(isset($_GET['q'])){

    //all you server code


    }
```

Comment: bro it bring all records then when i press any key

Comment: yhea that's why use isset and strlen to 2 or 3 char  and use select name, id , age, sex from name where name like '$in%'

Comment: done thanks bro i should get q rather than str thanks bro

Comment: Can I select multiple columns in where clause like where name,sex,age="$in%";  ???

Comment: u need to use or clause i.e. where name="" or sex ="" or age=""

Comment: and mark it resolved on clicking the tick just below voteup and votedown.

Comment: yhea buddy no issues

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file you are trying to fetch `str` from the request:

```
$in=$_GET['str'];
```

But, in your js you are sending the `q`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?q="+str, true);
```

Change this to

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?str="+str, true);
```

### Update:

In your ajax query, add the extra parameter you need:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?str="+str+'&name='+name+'&age='+age true);
```

Assuming, you know how to get the name and age values from you html.

In your PHP add these parameters to your query.

```
$sql = "select name, id , age, sex from name where name like '%$in%' AND age = `$age`";
```

Comment: Can I select multiple columns in where clause like where name,sex,age="$in%";  ???

Comment: yes you can.. just add more parameters to your ajax query

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing, parameter that you declare in your GET Url is not `str` but `q`.

so, change to `$_GET['q']`

Comment: anytime bro, don't forget to vote up this answer and other answers which is true

Comment: Can I select multiple columns in where clause like where name,sex,age="$in%";  ???

Comment: no mate, you have to declare it one by one like `name like '".$in."%' and sex like '".$in."%'` and so on